# Retreiving a list of fonts from any PDF with PHP

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, preg-match, preg-match-all

I'm trying to retrieve a list of all fonts used in an uploaded PDF. The following script works fine for certain PDF's, but when fonts are listed in the PDF on the same line, the script doesn't find the next font, only the first.

```
$box="/BaseFont\ ?.*/";
$stream = new SplFileObject($pdffile); 
while (!$stream->eof()) {
    if (preg_match_all($box, $stream->fgets(), $matches)) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($matches[0]); $i++) {
            $newfont = substr($matches[0][$i], (strpos($matches[0][$i],"+") + 1));
            if (strpos($newfont,"/") > 0)
                {
                $newfont = str_replace(' ', '',substr($newfont, 0, strpos($newfont,"/")));
                $newfont = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '',$newfont);
                }
            if (!in_array($newfont, $fonts))
                {
                $fontcount = $fontcount + 1;
                echo $newfont."<br>";
                array_push($fonts,$newfont);
                }
        }
    }
}
$stream = null;
```

A sample of the PDF:

```
<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Wingdings-Regular/DescendantFonts 27 0 R/Encoding/Identity-H/Subtype/Type0/ToUnicode 28 0 R/Type/Font>>
endobj
14 0 obj
<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Roboto-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/FontDescriptor 30 0 R/LastChar 116/Subtype/TrueType/ToUnicode 31 0 R/Type/Font/Widths[249 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 873 708 0 651 0 0 634 0 0 636 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 518 0 529 0 564 564 267 0 0 267 0 564 564 0 0 0 516 349]>>
endobj
15 0 obj
<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Roboto-Light/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/FontDescriptor 33 0 R/LastChar 127/Subtype/TrueType/ToUnicode 34 0 R/Type/Font/Widths[243 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 239 397 583 554 554 554 554 0 554 554 554 554 0 0 0 0 0 0 913 625 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 538 557 518 0 515 329 557 557 227 0 0 227 886 557 557 557 0 340 509 332 557 0 757 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 323]>>
endobj
```

Which is really:

```
<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Wingdings-Regular/DescendantFonts 27 0 R/Encoding/Identity-H/Subtype/Type0/ToUnicode 28 0 R/Type/Font>>endobj14 0 obj<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Roboto-Bold/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/FontDescriptor 30 0 R/LastChar 116/Subtype/TrueType/ToUnicode 31 0 R/Type/Font/Widths[249 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 873 708 0 651 0 0 634 0 0 636 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 518 0 529 0 564 564 267 0 0 267 0 564 564 0 0 0 516 349]>>endobj15 0 obj<</BaseFont/CMYBYX+Roboto-Light/Encoding/WinAnsiEncoding/FirstChar 32/FontDescriptor 33 0 R/LastChar 127/Subtype/TrueType/ToUnicode 34 0 R/Type/Font/Widths[243 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 239 397 583 554 554 554 554 0 554 554 554 554 0 0 0 0 0 0 913 625 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 538 557 518 0 515 329 557 557 227 0 0 227 886 557 557 557 0 340 509 332 557 0 757 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 323]>>endobj
```

My last solution would be reading the file line by line and search line by line for fonts. But that would increase the processing time too much.

Anybody a suggestion? Different pattern (tried several)?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?

Comment: And "reading the file line by line and search line by line for fonts" is exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I need the font list to add text later; while the user can choose from the fonts already in the PDF. And by readind it line by line, I ment: open text file, while not eof get line, search line, next line, close file. Tried that, and it took about 4 times as long in processing.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the pattern to:

```
$box="/BaseFont\ ?.*>>/U";
```

Explanation:

- the most important change is the `U` at the end, it is called a pattern modifier - see [Pattern Modifiers](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) - it is used to make the matching non greedy, so it won't match the whole line since it responds to the pattern, but only as soon as it finds a `>>`
- talking about `>>` it is the second add to your pattern, it is necessary so it matches the whole BaseFont definition, or else it was matching only the word `BaseFont`, since the match is non greedy.

Comment: I am using both now, since some PDF"s font lists don't have '>>'.